# Windows 10 UAP change color theme

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How programmatically change the theme (for example from Dark to Light) of my application? I think I can redefine system resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows Phone 8.1**, you can set the **RequestedTheme** attribute on any control, or even at the app level to **override the Theme set by the users in the Settings**.

***Example for Light theme:***

*In code*, within the constructor of the App class :

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    private TransitionCollection transitions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;

        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
    }
}
```

Or *in XAML* :

```
<Application
    x:Class="App26.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    xmlns:local="using:App26">
</Application>
```

For **Dark Theme**

*In code*, within the constructor of the App class :

Replace

```
this.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;
```

with

```
this.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Dark;
```

In your App Code or

Or *in XAML* :

```
RequestedTheme="Dark"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [RequestedThemeProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme). You can change it from xaml or code behind for every page, control etc.

For example:
`RequestedTheme="Light"`